# add to a list in tuple with search in python

Tags: python, string, list, search, addition

i have a class (**cls**) with 2 main strings (**str1**, **str2**) and a list of strings (**strlist**)

python makes the strlist into a tuple so when i want to append to it i use

```
tmp=list(strlist)
tmp.append(addToList)
self.list=tmp
```

may not the best option but its the only one i could make with low knowledge of python

now i make things more complicated
i have list of cls (**clslist**) and i want to add another string to the strlist where str1 = A && str2 = B

how do create a search that will search for a match in the clslist and if found will add the new string to strlist

**EDIT 1**

```
class cls ():
    def __init__ (self,str1,str2,strlist):
        self.str1 = str1
        self.str2 = str2 
        self.strlist = strlist
```

and the main

```
def main():
    clslist =[]
    clslist.append(cls ("aaa","bbb",("123","456"))
```

i want to find the cls in the clslist where str1 = aaa and str2 = bbb and then add another string to the str list

so i will end up like this ("aaa","bbb",("123","456","789"))

Comment: What are ``A`` and ``B``? You also say *'python makes the strlist into a tuple'*, where and why? Please post your class, otherwise it's very hard to work out what is going on.

Comment: @Lattyware A and B are strings as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since clslist is unsorted your search will need to be linear.

For example:

```
for i in clslist:
    if i.str1 == A and i.str2 == B:
        i.strlist.append(whatever)
```

Answer (score 3):

Python doesn't make strlist a tuple, you are passing a tuple in. If you want a list just use `[]` instead of `()`

```
clslist.append(cls("aaa", "bbb", ["123","456"])
```

Searching your clslist is easy

```
for item in clslist:
    if item.str1 == A and item.str2 == B:
        # do something
        item.strlist.append(otherstring)
```

If you *do* need to extend a tuple, you can do it like this

```
>>> ("foo", "bar")+("baz",)
('foo', 'bar', 'baz')
```

The `,` before the `)` means `("baz",)` is a tuple, and you can add tuples. Unlike `list.append`, this will create a new tuple, so is not as efficient as it needs to copy all the old references into the new tuple.

Comment: dame, too much ignorance from my part... need to remember not to play with code in 3am thx for clearing up [] () for me